# Simple QR-Code library for PHP

Tags: library, php, qr-code

My question is pretty close to [QR Code Generator Library (no web service)](/q/16794/185) – just for PHP instead of .NET: I want a small, light-weight PHP "library" (ideally a compact class) to generate QR Codes, mostly for texts. It shall not use any web services, but generate the codes on-site.

#### Requirements

- free and open source (FOSS/FLOSS)
- small and light-weight (ideally a single class file with max 50kiB)
- the "simple" from the title meaning: install via copy-the-file(s) must be possible – not e.g. requiring composer with 10 dependencies. Best no dependencies at all (except for "built-in"/ships-with-PHP, like `php-gd` to create/manipulate graphics)
- not using web services (local generation; can use e.g. php-gd to generate images)
- supports at least encoding text and URLs
- supports at least PHP 7+

#### Nice to have (but not strictly required)

- supporting other types, like VCards, calendar entries
- embedding logos (to make a QR code easier to identify visibly)
- setting foreground/background colors (if not possible, black on white is OK)
- setting size (could be done afterwards – but it's easier if supported directly)
- small resulting file size
- actively maintained (so support for future PHP versions has a chance)
- available at Github, GitLab or Codeberg, ideally incl. issue tracker (for support, feedback and possible contributions)

#### Not needed

- fancy stuff like crazy coloring or rotating QR cubes with sound (you know what I mean: KISS principle)

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries to perform such a task. Here's the ones that caught my attention:

[**`php-qrcode`**](https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode): simple, but supports many options:

```
echo '<img src="'.(new QRCode)->render("hello world").'" />';
```

[**`qr-code`**](https://github.com/endroid/qr-code): same:

```
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
$qrCode = new QrCode('Life is too short to be generating QR codes');
header('Content-Type: '.$qrCode->getContentType());
echo $qrCode->writeString();
```

[**`phpqrcode`**](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/): open source library, based on `libqrencode`.

```
<?php 
include('qrlib.php'); 
// outputs image directly into browser, as PNG stream 
QRcode::png('hello world');
```

Comment: Sounds nice. I forgot to explain "simple" it seems: 1) *requires* composer (and dependencies), so it's unfortunately out (a simple copy must suffice). 2) also requires composer, so same. 3) was last released 2010 (so not sure if it supports PHP 7 at all). Actually I had already seen 1+3 and ruled them out for the reasons given. **Thanks** & +1 nevertheless! My fault of not being detailed enough, will update my question accordingly.